# Cannot access protected property PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

trying to get values from object array, here is error and what i tried so far.

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($response->_value());//Call to undefined method OmiseCharge::_value() 
echo "<pre>";print_r($response->_value); //Cannot access protected property PHP
```

**actual array** :

```
OmiseCharge Object
(
    [OMISE_CONNECTTIMEOUT:OmiseApiResource:private] => 30
    [OMISE_TIMEOUT:OmiseApiResource:private] => 60
    [_values:protected] => Array
        (
            [object] => list
            [from] => 2012-08-01T00:00:00+00:00
            [to] => 2016-10-20T00:00:00+00:00
            [offset] => 0
            [limit] => 20
            [total] => 201
            [order] => chronological
            [location] => /charges
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [object] => charge
                            [id] => chrg_test_##############
                            [livemode] =>
```

Comment: please justify the -1 vote.

Comment: generally protected members of a class [can only be accessed within the class of by children of said class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). also `_values` in your array isn't a function, it's a variable name. finally `$response` isn't an array, it's an object, specifically an object instance of the `OmiseCharge` class

Comment: There is probably a method that will get those values. Something like `$response->getValues();` or similar.

Comment: @Memor-X i am getting this from api call what is the way to use this response variable ?

Comment: You should check the `OmiseCharge` class. It should contain a method that returns those values.

Comment: @BhavinRana no idea, don't recognize `OmiseCharge`. as Rasclatt has said there's probably a proper method for accessing the private and protected data (if it's supposed to be access). the documentation and sorucecode should have how your supposed to work with the return data of the API Call

Comment: Did you tried `$response->getValues();` as said by @Rasclatt

Comment: Please try to know the OmiseCharge class methods using get_class_methods function, have a look on this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php

Comment: @AlbertAkki - Call to undefined method OmiseCharge::getValues()

Comment: Look at @JahangirAlam mentions, the `get_class_methods('OmiseCharge')` that should list off methods you could try. Or you can search in the class folder for `return _values`, there might be something there. Also, this class should have some sort of Documentation site or Git or something??

Comment: **Many Thanks all the Contributors ! good to be with you guys.

Comment: @BhavinRana  can you try with `$response->getValues();` where `$response = your object`. `you used with ::(scope resolution operator)`

Comment: please justify the -1 vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 echo "<pre>";print_r($response->offsetGet('data'));
```

worked thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to access protected member of a call you need to implement getter method in class which are type of public.